# TreeView control in C#, select() and focus

Tags: c#, treeview

When I select a `Node` in the `TreeView`, it highlights and I show data based on that `Node`. When I select another `Control` (the `TreeView` loses focus) it is no longer highlighted. How do I keep it highlighted after losing focus?
While doing a search I cant tell which node is selected since I must keep the focus on the textbox (so the user can type more text).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set the HideSelection property to false - so you'll see the selection, altough the TreeView control lost focus

Comment: I must add that there are actually 3 TreeView classes in C#: WinForms, ASP.NET and WPF. Only the WinForms control has the HideSelection property.

Comment: This leaves me wondering why the Visual Studio designer assigns `true` as the default value of the `HideSelection` property. I would think that in the majority of use cases ***not*** hiding the currently selected node would be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

I just run into this issue and this is how I addressed it:  Changed the DrawMode property to `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText` and registered to DrawNode event

```
 
    private void MyTreeGridview_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) 
    {
        if ((e.State == TreeNodeStates.Selected) && (!MyTreeGridview.Focused))
        {
            Font font = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;
            Color fore = e.Node.ForeColor;
            if (fore == Color.Empty)fore = e.Node.TreeView.ForeColor;      
            fore = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            Color highlightColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(highlightColor), e.Bounds);
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, fore, highlightColor);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, e.Bounds, fore, highlightColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the highlight color isn't bright enough to your liking when HideSelection is set to False and the TreeView lost focus:

Make sure your TreeView's HideSelection is set to True (default value).

Then handle the TreeView's Enter and Leave events like:

```
void myTreeView_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as TreeView).SelectedNode != null)
        (sender as System.Windows.Forms.TreeView).SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Red; //your highlight color
}

void myTreeView_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as TreeView).SelectedNode != null)
        (sender as TreeView).SelectedNode.BackColor = (sender as TreeView).BackColor;
}
```